# How to delete lines from csv file that have only one record using dos batch file

Tags: csv, batch-file, line, dos

I need a dos batch file to delete single record lines for a multi line csv file.  The file is in the correct comma(,) separated variable format. I have been trying with "for /f" batch command with no luck.  In the example file below, the second and fourth line need to be deleted.

my_file.csv

string_1, string_2, string_3, string_4
string_1,
string_1, string_2, string_3, string_4, string_5, string_6, string_7, string_8
string_1,
string_1, string_2, string_3, string_4, string_5, string_6, string_7, string_8, string_9

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it saves the new csv in new_file.csv:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%i in (my_file.csv) do call:process "%%~i"
goto:eof

:process
set "line=%~1"
if "%line:*,=%"=="" goto:eof
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo !line!>>new_file.csv
endlocal
goto:eof
```

Answer (score 1):

In one line:

```
findstr /v /r ",$" myfile.csv >newfile.csv
```

which finds all lines that `/v` do not contain `/r` regular-expression `",$"` - a comma at the end of the line.